# merging two recordsets in ASP classic

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic

I have two MS Access databases and I am trying to create one recordset using a query from each one. The databases are located in a folder (db) above the root directory.

I have tried a lot of code combinations and the latest is;

```
Conn.Open "DBQ=" & server.mappath("../db") & "\dbaseg.mdb"& ";Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};"

strSQL="SELECT accom, name, address1, address2, town, county, postcode, telephone, link2, distance, account FROM ukgh where distance is not null and code='" & code & "' and airport='" & airport &  "' UNION  SELECT accom, name, address1, address2, town, county, postcode, telephone, link2, distance, account FROM uksc  IN 'D:\Webspace\mydomain.com\db\dbasesc.mdb' where distance is not null and code='" & code & "' and airport = '" & airport &  "' ORDER BY distance ASC"

set RS = Conn.Execute(strSQL)
```

This returns the error:

> [Microsoft][ODBC_Microsoft_Access_Driver]_'D:\Webspace\mydomain.com\db\dbasesc.mdb'_is_not_a_valid_path.__Make_sure_that_the_path_name_is_spelled_correctly_and_that_you_are_connected_to_the_server_on_which_the_file_resides.

If I change the query to:

```
strSQL="SELECT accom, name, address1, address2, town, county, postcode, telephone, link2, distance, account FROM ukgh where distance is not null and code='" & code & "' and airport='" & airport &  "' UNION  SELECT accom, name, address1, address2, town, county, postcode, telephone, link2, distance, account FROM uksc  IN"  & server.mappath("../db") & "\dbaseg.mdb where distance is not null and code='" & code & "' and airport = '" & airport &  "' ORDER BY distance ASC"
```

I get this error:

> 80040e14|[Microsoft][ODBC_Microsoft_Access_Driver]_Syntax_error_in_FROM_clause

I have also tried a few other possibilities but still cannot get it to work, which is very frustrating.

I am obviously doing something wrong, but cannot find a solution having used a lot of different search terms on the site and Google.

Is there a simpler way of merging two recordsets when each one is taken from a different database?

Comment: Why are you not linking the databases?  The data you need from the second database should be linked tables.  You're making this 20 times harder than it should be.

Comment: @JohnnyBones The reason is because I don't know how to do that on-line. I can find ways to do it on my PC but not on-line. Is there a way to do that with ASP classic?

Comment: OK I have now moved the table from one database to the other one, so the UNION works. It does mean that I have a rather large MS Access database now but I couldn't find a better way of doing it. Thanks for your help.